# Symfony propel-dump memory exhausted

Tags: php, memory, symfony1, limit, propel

im using symfony 1.4 with propel 1.5 and i can't dump my data :(

> > propel    dumping data to "C:\web\project\data\fixtures\dump.yml"

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 838860800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in C:\web\project\plugins\sfPropel15Plugin\lib\addon\sfPropelData.class.php on line 528
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 838860800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in C:\web\project\plugins\sfPropel15Plugin\lib\addon\sfPropelData.class.php on line 528

I have XAMPP and i have tried to changed memory limit to 900MB, and, as you see..there is a problem. With any previous projects it always was ok.

HELP!

I think its cause of 2-side relation(worker-department, department-worker) here:

```
  department:
    id:                    ~
    department_id:         ~
    project_id:            { type: integer, foreignTable: bank_project, foreignReference: id, required: true, onDelete: cascade }
    chief_id:              { type: integer, foreignTable: worker, foreignReference: id }
    evaluatable:           { type: boolean, default: 0 }

  worker:
    id:                    ~
    department_id:         { type: integer, foreignTable: department, foreignReference: id, required: true, onDelete: cascade }
    name:                  { type: varchar(255) }
    surname:               { type: varchar(255) }
    email:                 { type: varchar(255)}
    language:              { type: varchar(255) }
    code:                  { type: varchar(20),index: unique }
```

but how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you propel you have a self referential structure which propel can't solve because of foreign key constraints. A temporary solution would be to manually drop the foreign key constraints in your DB and then dump the data and add the foreign key constraints again (see also http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/3256).

At the moment I'm looking for a better solution, since I ran into this problem when I was programming an automatic update script that should update several websites. If I find a general, easy-to-use solution I let you know.

Comment: Add the next paragraph as a comment. As it is extra information you want to provide with your answer.